# Unable to login to Rest API with spring security

Tags: java, spring-security, rest-assured, spring-rest, web-api-testing

I need to automate REST API using REST Assured API, but getting issues.
Using REST Assured API, I need to login with Spring Security configuration.

Please have a look at the code below :

```java
@Before
public void configure() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://example.com";
        RestAssured.basePath = "/my-portal";
}

@Test
public void apiLogin() {
    given().auth().form("username", "password", springSecurity().withLoggingEnabled(new LogConfig())).when().get();
}
```

The problem I am facing is:

**Actual Request URI**: `https://example.com/j_spring_security_check` 
**Expected Request URI**: `https://example.com/my-portal/j_spring_security_check`

The following is the response fetched:

```
Request method: POST
Request URI:    https://example.com/j_spring_security_check
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    j_username={username}
                j_password={password}
Path params:    <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Headers:        Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1
Cookies:        <none>
Body:           <none>
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 06 Feb 2017 10:51:41 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Comment: Can anybody answer here : https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/815

Answer (score 0):

I got this working. Just few mistake and it worked.

Below is the working code :

```
final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        final PrintStream captor = new PrintStream(new WriterOutputStream(writer), true);
        Response s = given().auth().
                        form(userName, password,
                        FormAuthConfig.springSecurity().withLoggingEnabled(new LogConfig(captor, true)))
                .post("/home/myapp.html");

        System.out.println(s.getBody().asString());
```

It provides the HTTP status code : 302 (i.e. redirect to page /home/myapp.html).